# Can you call shell_exec() from sapUI5?

Tags: php, sapui5

I am using sapUI5 and code igniter. I am calling a function in php code igniter controller from an ajax in ui5. This function has the command `shell_exec('powershell.exe Move-Item -Path "'.$path.'" -Destination somepath')`. For some reason the move command isn't working. I checked the paths and they are all correct. Hence I was wondering can you call shell_exec() from sapui5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, you cannot run OS related command in browser.

You need to make it in backend look like your php code. php has [**rename**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) command for move or renaming file.

If you want to use [**shell_exec**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), you need to check result of it. May be you can get permission error or file in use.